# R^ 2 with dictionary order topology is metrizable

Tags: general-topology

This problem is from topology by  munkres book. Need ideas to solve this.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: In essence: a disjoint sum of metric spaces is metrisable.